# How to Filter view by comparing 2 fields. If field-a < field-b

Tags: 7, views, commerce

I have a product content type that has 2 price fields.

I want to create a view that shows all products where price-A is less than price-B.

I was hoping I could just add a filter and select price-A then choose operate less than and set the value as price-B, however you can't do that.

I have looked into using a views hook, mainly hook_views_query_alter but haven't had any luck.

I've also tried using the Views PHP module and been unable to get it to work.

Does anyone know the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 12):

What you're looking for is the filter criteria `Global: Fields comparison`:)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: For Drupal 8/9 etc there's a contrib module, https://www.drupal.org/project/views_field_compare

Answer (score 4):

Welcome to the Drupal Answers Stack Exchange ! There is no straight forward way to achieve this in Drupal views as of now, and as i know.

You can do this using [Views PHP](http://drupal.org/project/views_php) module. Enable this module and add a filter PHP filter which you can select from views filter Global Category once you install above module.

Add php code some thing like below in the PHP code section of filter.

```
$node = node_load($data->nid);

$field_a = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_price_a');
$price_a = field_view_value('node', $node, 'field_price_a', $field_a[0]);

$field_b = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_price_b');
$price_b = field_view_value('node', $node, 'field_price_b', $field_b[0]);

if ($price_a >= $price_b) {
  return TRUE;
}
```

Change the field_price_a with your Price A field name and field_price_b with your Price B field name.

I tested and it worked for me ! Hope you can crack it too :-)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm still unable to get it working with this bit of code and have used the fields that show up when doing dsm($data);

I think I just might add in a checkbox as well and filter if checkbox is checked. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Meanwhile, it is possible with views, without any custom coding oder any contributed module needed.

Answer (score 0):

This functionality is now included in Views starting with version 7.x-3.8. See https://www.drupal.org/node/699252#comment-7513087 for more.

Answer (score -1):

http://drupal.org/project/views_dependent_filters is pretty useful...

The add-button of "Filter Criteria" has new submenues. Selfexplaning once you try it...

EDIT: sorry, but not for > or <, but for filtergroups which can be seperated by OR

Answer (score -2):

If price is a field in your content type, in Drupal 7 views you can automatically, and easily choose a field com-parer. I guess this should work.