# How to compare two fields for filter criteria in view

Tags: views

[image]

I want to compare this field value with another field value

How can I do that?

Thank you very much!

Comment: You can consider the solution provided [here][1].


  [1]: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/44097/how-to-filter-view-by-comparing-2-fields-if-field-a-field-b/44100#44100

Comment: thank you, but view php module is still in dev version.

Comment: i use hook_views_query_alter to achieve my goal. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: Check the other answers on suggested solution, too.

Answer (score 4):

With latest views in 7 you have under global filters, "field comparison" filter that you can select any 2 fields which you added into fields of that view (they can be hidden fields) and that is it. Image below shows how this looks:

[image]

Comment: Is this still accurate? I can't seem to get it to come up in D8. I've got two node ID fields (one is a relationship), and I want to filter as long as those two ID fields are the same, but I'm only seeing Combine Filters in Global.

Comment: Same issue, this does not seem to be included in D8. There is a "combine" but no "compare" fields

Comment: D8 issue tracking the feature: https://www.drupal.org/node/699252