# How to filter view based on a parent node

Tags: views, entities

On my website, i have some **products** and some **master products**.

Each **products** depend on a **master product**, which can have multiple products under itself. There are 2 different content type.

In the product content type, **master product** is an **Entity Reference**.

I'm trying to filter my view to get all *similar products* : basically, i need a view to get all products that have the same **tint** has the current product.

The tricky part is that the **tint** is a field of the master product.

Does anyone has any part of an answer?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are displaying all similar products on another node page - load the master node by adding an entity reference relationship to your view. I don't think you can  compare values of two different nodes in a view. So, Use the [view PHP](http://drupal.org/project/views_php) module to write a filter script that can compare both the fields from the nodes.

Check out this ['Question'](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/44097/how-to-filter-view-by-comparing-2-fields-if-field-a-field-b/44100#44100) on using the [view PHP](http://drupal.org/project/views_php) module