# Filter nodes matching user account field [list (text)] using different field names but same key

Tags: views, nodes, 7, users

There is a field of type *list (text)* [`field_list_user`] on user accounts and a field of type *list (text)* [`field_list_node`] on nodes. Both fields have exactly the same keys but different labels [and field names]. Any content of the site can be authored by users.

Is it possible to create a block with nodes for a currently logged-in user filtered like: value (key) of `field_list_user` = `field_list_node`?

Comment: Have a look at [Equi Join](https://www.drupal.org/project/equi_join)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is module to do a filter that compare 2 arbitrary value but you can add a php filter using [Views PHP module](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_php)

Then, you can create a PHP filter in your view.
Someone write an example that is quite similar to what you need : https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/44100/36824

Comment: I thought so. I've tried to achieve this using relations and contextual filters in Views but couldn't produce a block like that. Thanks for your advice.