# How to contextual filter a view by a field value?

Tags: 7, entities

### QUESTION

I have an address field in my user form, from the [address field](https://www.drupal.org/project/addressfield) module.

I have a content type named "project" which also have an address field and users can pick up a country related to the country the project will belong to.

I want to make a view filtering all the projects related to the logged-in user's address country field.

### TRY

My trick is to make a **user-view** with a author-content relationship filtered on the content type project. Now I have the two fields in the view, I'm trying to compare them with a contextual php filter.

I tried to use php filter based on [this post](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/44097/how-to-filter-view-by-comparing-2-fields-if-field-a-field-b)

```
$node = node_load($data->nid);
$user = user_load($user->uid);

$field_user_country = field_get_items('user', $user, 'field_user_address_country');
$country_user = field_view_value('user', $user, 'field_user_country', $field_user_country[0]);

$field_project_country = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_project_range_country_country');
$project_country = field_view_value('node', $node, 'field_project_country', $$field_project_country[0]);

if ($price_a = $price_b) {
  return TRUE;
}
```

The fact is *field_user_address_country* is actually stored under *field_data_field_user_address* in the database.

Same for *field_project_range_country_country* which is stored under *field_data_field_project_range_country*

What is the best way to do this ? Is what I'm trying to do possible ?

### UPDATE 1

Clear code which give me an ajax error :

```
$node = node_load($data->nid);
$user = user_load($user->uid);

$field_user_country = field_get_items('user', $user, 'field_user_address_country');
$country_user = field_view_value('user', $user, 'field_user_address_country', $field_user_country[0]);

$field_project_country = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_project_range_country_country');
$project_country = field_view_value('node', $node, 'field_project_range_country_country', $field_project_country[0]);

if ($country_user == $project_country) {
  return TRUE;
```

### UPDATE 2

Here the new code which is still giving me an ajax error :

> EntityMalformedException : Missing bundle property on entity of type
>   node

```
$node = node_load($data->nid);
$user = user_load($user->uid);

$field_user_country = field_get_items('user', $user, 'field_user_address_country');
$country_user = field_view_value('user', $user, 'field_user_address_country', $field_user_country[0]);

$field_project_country = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_project_range_country_country');
$project_country = field_view_value('node', $node, 'field_project_range_country_country', $field_project_country[0]);

if ($country_user == $project_country) {
  return $country_user;
}
```

Have a bigger ajax error (like 15 lines) if I put

```
global $user 
$node = ($node = menu_get_object()) ? $node->nid : NULL;
```

At the beginning of my code.

Comment: `if ($price_a = $price_b) {` here you are setting $price_a equal to $price_b rather than checking if $price_a is equal to $price_b. You need to use `==` when performing checks. So this needs to be ``if ($price_a == $price_b) {``

Comment: Yes surely. Was a newbie php mistake. It's still doesn't work.

Comment: That's because in your code $price_a and $price_b variables do not exist. try `if ($country_user == $project_country) {` also fix remove 1 `$` from `$$field_project_country[0]`

Comment: Yeah yeah I've noticed that. But still, making a comparison between $country_user == $project_country give me an ajax error.

Comment: I aslo noticed that to use "field_view_value" function I should put the name of the field as 3rd argument and not the name of the variable previously defined. But still ajax error. In fact I presume that I can't get $data->nid and $user->uid from node_load and user_load. Trying to print them gave me an undefined variable error ....

Comment: Yes, that is correct, those 2 are undefined. You can fix the user one by adding `global $user;` at the top. For the nid follow [What's the cleanest way to get the NID of the current node from a module (NOT a template)?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/32309/whats-the-cleanest-way-to-get-the-nid-of-the-current-node-from-a-module-not-a)

Comment: you also want to `return $country_user;` instead of `TRUE;`. That code is really a mess, I can write you the proper code, just need to finish some work for a client first.

Comment: Thanks I've corrected some unproper code and put what you told to me but it's still not working. Wasn't node_load and user_load supposed to call $user and $node variable (whereas global $user and $node->nid) ?

Comment: possibly because you have `field_project_range_country_country` <-- you have country twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a block view of Show: content, in contextual filter add Country.

Add this to your view contextual filter:

```
  global $user; // gets current logged in user object

  if (isset($user->field_user_address[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['country'])) {      
    $user_country = $user->field_user_address[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['country'];
    return $user_country;
  }
```

Comment: Rhaa, I'm not having an ajax error but still : Undefined property: stdClass::$field_project_range_country and Undefined property: stdClass::$field_user_address_country. Does variables gets values from the views fields (which are from the node) or from the node fields themselves ? If it's from the node maybe it's because the both fields are from an array from address_field ?

Comment: I tested this, I used the [address field module](https://www.drupal.org/project/addressfield). It gets them from nodes and user (not from views). Sounds like you have a different machine names for your fields? Check in Manage Display under the Machine Name column. Are you sure they are the same as my code? `field_project_range_country` and `field_user_address_country`

Comment: So, for the user page I have just one address field (which contain country, city and street references) with the machine name `field_user_address`. I picked up the `field_user_address_country` name from the mysql database. And for my content type "project" I have an address field which just contain country references with the machine name `field_project_range_country`. I don't know why we can't succed to have the field from the project page at least ...

Comment: In my code, adjust the user machine name and see what happens

Comment: When I did my test I had both with address, city, country, postal.

Comment: Ok, I catch one by changing `field_user_address_country` by `field_user_address` but the project one is actually called `field_project_range_country` but just stored country datas. Sorry I tried to figure it out by myself but I'm so bad in php ...

Comment: I'm in bed, using mobile. I'll redo the test with node just having country when I wake up in 8hrs or so, what field type did u use for node?.

Comment: @Aporie same code still works fine for me. [This is how I set up the node](https://i.stack.imgur.com/igq1y.jpg)

Comment: Aporie, if you want, I can help you with [TeamViewer](https://www.teamviewer.com/en/?pid=google.tv.exact.s.ca&gclid=CIn9oprXhNICFU2SfgodCdsIwQ), it's free for personal use. This app allows me to see and control your PC from mine (screen sharing).

Comment: Yeah my setup is exactly the same ... I don't know why it's not working. Sure for teamviewer. Can we send private message on stackexchange ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53392/discussion-between-no-sssweat-and-aporie).

Comment: @Aporie updated my answer. The `$uid = $user->uid; // gets user id` and
`$user = user_load($uid); // loads the user` lines are not necessary, since global $user already has loaded the current user.

Comment: Thanks for updated me. Actually it's a little piece of code that made me lot of trouble. I'm gonna look the difference between global user and user_load.

Comment: @Aporie `global $user` is the current logged in user, while `user_load()` is used for non current logged in user cases. Ex: a profile page for /user/5 you would want to use user_load here.

Comment: OK. Good to know. Will surely be useful for others views I will have to do.